# Upload multiple Gradle artifacts to Artifactory from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

My environment uses Gradle for builds, Jenkins for CI, and Artifactory for a repository. I use the Artifactory plugin for Jenkins.

Jenkins successfully builds my main jar file and uploads it to Artifactory. The build script has a second target for creating a distribution zip file under build/distributions. Jenkins creates the zip file successfully, but I don't know how to tell it to upload that artifact to Artifactory, too.

Is this something I should be able to specify in the Jenkins Artifactory plugin config, or something I should define in the Gradle build script? Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have configured artifactory server correctly in *Manage Jenkins* section; also your job is setup as a *Freestyle Project*.

Select your job and click *Configure*.  Check *Generic Artifactory Integration* in **Build Environment**. Select your *Artifactory Server* and *Target Repository* from drop downs, check *Override default deployer credentials* if required. In *Published Artifacts* you enter the pattern for your zip file to be published, e.g. `${WORKSPACE}/distr/*.zip` (where by *WORKSPACE* is jenkins current project's workspace and *distr/*.zip* your distribution zip file). Check if required *Capture and publish build info*, *Include environment variables* etc. Save your job. When you build it the next time, the zip file will be uploaded and will be available in the *Builds* section on artifactory.

Comment: Thank you MrsTang! For some reason I had checked _Gradle Artifactory Integration_, so I didn't get the _Published Artifacts_ section.

Answer (score 5):

You should configure the `archives` configuration to include all the archives you intend to publish as described in [Gradle's user manual](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#artifact_management). Not only Artifactory will pick up all the files to deploy automatically (without messing with *Published Artifacts* configuration), you won't even need to run the second task. All the archives will be creating by running the `build` task.

Comment: Awesome. Your solution is tied to the project, not Jenkins.