# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin does not publish artifacts using Gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I have an incredibly basic Gradle build file:

```
plugins {
    id "base"
    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.3.0"
}
configurations {
    batchConfig
}
artifacts{
    file("dist").eachFile{ zipFile ->
        batchConfig zipFile
    }
}

println "BatchConfig Artifacts: " + configurations.batchConfig.allArtifacts
```

This is executed via Jenkins and appears to work fine:

> Archives Artifacts: [DefaultPublishArtifact_Decorated
>   module-0.0.post0.dev6+n4c62094-py2.7:egg:egg:null]
>
> [buildinfo] Properties file found at
>   '/tmp/buildInfo65481565498521.properties'
>
> :artifactoryPublish
>
> Deploying build descriptor to:
>   https://ourArtifactoryServer/artifactory/api/build
>
> Build successfully deployed.
>
> Browse it in Artifactory under
>   https://ourArtifactoryServer/artifactory/webapp/builds/testGradleBuild/34
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL

However the artifact is not actually uploaded to Artifactory at all.

SSL cert configuration appears to be working fine, as I had to address that first.  Any suggestions as to what I'm missing here?

Comment: Note that when I use the Generic Plugin as per [@MrsTang 's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14587102/3204277) the artifact in question is published, however I want to take advantage of the full Gradle Plugin :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you do still need to utilise the artifactory closure outlined in the [Gradle Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin).  Switching back to using "archives" instead of a custom Config and then adding this to my build sorted it:

```
artifactory {
    publish {
        defaults {
            publishConfigs('archives')
        }
    }
}
```